# Proper way to iterate (foreach) with separator

Tags: php, foreach

The foreach construct below works just fine if the items returned are more than one. However, if there is only one item displayed the separator | is still being retained.

What's wrong with my code below?

```
<?php 
foreach ($array->items as $item) {
       $len = count($item);
            if ($i < $len) {    
               print '<a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a>' . ' | ';
            }

            else {  
               print '<a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a>';
            }
        $i++;               
}
?>
```

Comment: Quote your strings: "Health and Wellness"

Comment: Forget about that condition. I removed it but still the same.

Comment: Well, where is the logic to handle the case where there is only one element in the array? That's right: you didn't write any! Step through the loop on paper and you will see what the problem is..

Comment: using implode accounts for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$echos=array();
foreach ($array->items as $item) {
    $echos[]= '<a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a>';
}
print implode(' | ', $echos);
```